# conflict with foreign key constraint when inserting data

Tags: sql-server

These are my tables and they got created but when I am inserting data in `AMI` tables it gives me foreign key conflict error. I understand that the before inserting into child table , parent should have that value. Here my AMI table is dependent on both `household_income` and `location` and both has data. So why I am getting the error:

```
Insert into AMI values('CONTROL','ZIP','PER','L30','L50','L80');
```

> Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Line 1 The INSERT statement conflicted with the >FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK__AMI__7908F585". The conflict occurred in database >"mydatabase_old", table "dbo.household_income".
>   The statement has been terminated.

```
create table admin
(control   varchar(15), 
status     varchar(3),
weight     float(24),
metro3     varchar(3),
PRIMARY KEY (control)
);



create table AMI 
(control varchar(15),
zip    varchar(8),
per     VARCHAR(15),
L30         int,
L50         int,
L80         int,
PRIMARY KEY(zip, per),
foreign key (zip, control) references location on delete cascade,
foreign key (per, control) references household_income ON UPDATE NO ACTION
);



create table location
(region varchar(5),
control   varchar(15),
zip    varchar(8),
PRIMARY KEY(zip, control),
foreign key (control) references admin on delete cascade
);


create table household_income
(control   varchar(15),
age1    int,
per    varchar(15),
ownrent     varchar(3),
totalsal    float(24),
zinc2       float(24),
type        varchar(15), 
PRIMARY KEY(control, per),
foreign key (control) references admin on delete cascade,
foreign key (type, control) references structure ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
);
```

Comment: You are trying to insert data in to child table before inserting data in Parent Table .when we referential integrity was applied on schema .you should enter the data in to parent table first then followed by child

Comment: As per my understanding AMI is my child table and both location and household_income are the parent table. i.e household_income has control and per...and location has control and zip...and then i am inserting that data into AMI

Answer (score 0):

First you need to insert into location table

and then into household_income

and then do your insert

```
Insert into AMI values('CONTROL','ZIP','PER','L30','L50','L80');
```

Comment: I did that : 
select * from household_income where control = 100003130103 -->
100003130103 82 1 1 0 1 1       ;

select * from [location] where control = 100003130103  -->
1 100003130103 73738    ;;


Insert into AMI values('100003130103','73738','1','15738','26213','40322');  but i do not what is missing here? Can you please help

Comment: you are trying to insert string values into int column, try this: Insert into AMI values('100003130103','73738','1',15738,26213,40322);